# Unbound Module Stdlib

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I am trying to build code using ocamlc however, I got error
`Error: Unbound module Stdlib`

The `/usr/lib/ocaml/` directory includes the following
`stdlib.a`   `stdlib.cma` `stdlib.cxma`   `stdlib.p.a`  `stdlib.p.cxma`

OCaml version : 4.05.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library was renamed from Pervasives to Stdlib fairly recently. Your compiler is from before the change; i.e., the 4.05.0 compiler has a Pervasives module and no Stdlib module. The code you're trying to compile is most likely from after the change.

There's usually no reason to mention the name of the standard library because it is "pervasive". So you could try removing "Stdlib." wherever you see it. Or you could try renaming it to "Pervasives.".

If the code is much more recent than the 4.05.0 compiler you could encounter other problems, however.

Answer (score 1):

The `Stdlib` module was introduced in 4.07.0. Before that it was called `Pervasives`. It seems like you're mixing installations.

A few commands that might help untangle it:

- `which ocamlc` will tell you where the compiler is located.
- `ocamlc -config` will tell you where the standard library is expected to be.

It is also strongly advised to use [`opam`](https://opam.ocaml.org/), the OCaml Package Manager, to manage OCaml installations as it allows you to switch between multiple installations and gives you access to the latest compiler as soon as  it's released.